# Infinispan: MissingBackpressureException when putting entries too fast

Tags: rx-java, infinispan

I have a strange problem with Infinispan: it throws a lot of those given below exceptions when I try to put entries into it faster that a few hundred rows per second (which isn't that fast at all).

My configuration:

- Tested on Infinispan 13 and 14
- Infinispan is embedded in Wildfly 26 and uses jdbc-store in "Write Behind" mode.
- I've tried many different configurations of jdbc-store and nothing helps.

Web search engines have no answers for Infinispan+MissingBackpressureException query.

Any ideas for a solution would be very appreciated.

This is the root exception:

```
Caused by: io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException: Unable to emit a new group (#128) due to lack of requests. Please make sure the downstream can always accept a new group as well as each group is consumed in order for the whole operator to be able to proceed.
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGroupBy$GroupBySubscriber.onNext(FlowableGroupBy.java:197)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.tryOnNext(FlowableFilter.java:75)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFilter.java:53)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowablePublish$PublishConnection.drain(FlowablePublish.java:312)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowablePublish$PublishConnection.onSubscribe(FlowablePublish.java:208)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15863)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowablePublish.connect(FlowablePublish.java:93)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableAutoConnect.subscribeActual(FlowableAutoConnect.java:50)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:38)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:38)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGroupBy.subscribeActual(FlowableGroupBy.java:73)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:38)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:51)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15917)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15863)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableLastMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableLastMaybe.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:5375)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Maybe.blockingSubscribe(Maybe.java:2989)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.rxjava//io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Maybe.blockingSubscribe(Maybe.java:2960)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc@14.0.2.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.sql.BaseTableOperations.batchUpdates(BaseTableOperations.java:202)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Infinispan. They fixed it an hour ago https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14509 :)